# Run colab notebook from last output rather tha from scratch

Tags: google-colaboratory

I ran notebook in google colab yesterday say till cell 42 and there were some function which took a lot of time and I want to run it tomorrow continuing after cell 42 rather than from cell 0.
How can we do it?

I tried to google solution but didn't find much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Colab session times out after a while and then you must load all your elements to continue.

Comment: So every day I will have to re run it then? Also can i do it locally then or there is any other way?

Comment: In case you don't want to store checkpoints locally, you can save your intermediate results in Google Drive and load them at the start of the session. The way you store it depends on the type of data you operate.